# A program that reads a name in a certain format. Introduction to scripting

Tags: scripting, format

Many documents use a specific format for a person's name. Write a program that reads a person's name in the following format:

firstName middleName lastName (in one line)

and outputs the person's name in the following format:

lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial.

Ex: If the input is:

Pat Silly Doe
the output is:

Doe, P.S.
If the input has the following format:

firstName lastName (in one line)

the output is:

lastName, firstInitial.

Ex: If the input is:

Julia Clark
the output is:

Clark, J.

```
Name = str(input())
token = Name.split()
if token == 3:
   print(token[2] + ',', token[0][0] + '.' + token[1][0] + '.')
else:
    print(token[1] + ',', token[0][0] + '.')
```

I thought the 3: would help me discern when the name is last and first initial or three(lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial.)

Comment: Please, if this question is inappropriate, advise me. I posted a foolish question in the past.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your professor is not reading SO, otherwise you might fail class... It is wise not to copy paste exactly the instructions you got in your Intro to DS course :)